# Messed up NPM trying to solve EACCESS on -g installs

Tags: npm, truffle

I've been using `sudo npm install -g ...` for years now and I've always read it's bad practice. I finally decided to solve the issue while starting a new project and found https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally which seemed a good resource to fix the issue. I followed the instructions up to `source ~/.profile` on which I received the message `-bash: ~/.profile: No such file or directory`. I then tried to run `npm i -g truffle` and while the installation went great, if I now try to run `truffle migrate` it says `-bash: truffle: command not found`.

I think I messed up a little with my profile etc and I am not sure how to fix the problem (and possibly never use `sudo npm i -g ...` ever again). What can I do to fix my issue?

Thanks!

EDIT: running `npm i -g jshint` seems to work. Installing truffle doesn't work though. The problem is that I see `/usr/local/bin/jshint` so jshint works, but I don't see `/usr/local/bin/truffle` so truffle is not working...?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, not sure if it's a permanent solution but here's how I did it. First of all I checked that in `/Users/[my-user]/npm-global/bin` there was indeed truffle and it was working. I then created an alias in my .bash_profile (alias truffle='pathtotruffle') and sourced it. Now I can use truffle without sudo!